# How to Create Emboss and engrave text on OpenCASCADE

Tags: opencascade

I am searching an API for creating emboss text on my AIS_Shape , If there is no API any better way to do that ?,I am thinking of creating text extrude and doing cut operation with AIS_Shape , can we extrude Text ?

Answer (score 0):

OCCT doesn't provide direct tool defining an emboss text - so you are right, you have to do that using a general Boolean operation.

A general idea can be found within standard samples coming with Draw Harness - take a look onto "Modeling" -> "OCCT Tutorial bottle sample" sample (`source $env(CSF_OCCTSamplesPath)/tcl/bottle.tcl`):

[image: Bottle Demo in Draw Harness]

Tools to use:

- `Font_BRepFont` to load a font and convert a glyph into a planar `TopoDS_Shape`.
- `Font_BRepTextBuilder` to format a text using `Font_BRepFont`.
- `BRepPrimAPI_MakePrism` to define a solid from text.
- `BRepAlgoAPI_Cut` to perform a Boolean operation between text solid and another shape.

Here is a pseudo-code:

```cpp
  // text2brep
  const double aFontHeight = 20.0;
  Font_BRepFont aFont (Font_NOF_SANS_SERIF, Font_FontAspect_Bold, aFontHeight);
  Font_BRepTextBuilder aBuilder;
  TopoDS_Shape aTextShape2d = aBuilder.Perform (aFont, "OpenCASCADE");

  // prism
  const double anExtrusion = 5.0;
  BRepPrimAPI_MakePrism aPrismTool (aTextShape2d, gp_Vec (0,0,1) * anExtrusion);
  TopoDS_Shape aTextShape3d = aPrismTool->Shape();
  //aTextShape3d.SetLocation(); // move where needed

  // bopcut
  TopoDS_Shape theMainShape; // defined elsewhere
  BRepAlgoAPI_Cut aCutTool (theMainShape, aTextShape3d);
  if (!aCutTool.IsDone()) { error }
  TopoDS_Shape aResult = aCutTool.Shape();
```